# stdin: error 0 - what does it mean?

Tags: boot

In the course of my adventures in Ubuntu, I've encountered the mysterious black screen with the single line

> stdin: error 0

at boot many times. But what does it ***mean***? Is it Kernel level? Is it bootloader? Or is it just a generic error that means "oops"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short its an error reading *something* although what is a little hard to diagnose without a little more information.

I've seen it on my machine, at boot, if I've got a CD in my drive that can't be read. It also turns up on drives/ram that is failing.

Those examples are *not* exhaustive, however, so I wouldn't go worrying unless you've got any other evidence of hardware issues.